Bun.js Packet losses in Websocket
I created a Websocket server using Bun.serve(). In this server, when a new client connects, I send it 1 million packets with a for loop. But these packets are interrupted. Hundreds of thousands of packets are not sent to the client. I used the ws package from NPM instead of Bun's Websocket and the problem is solved. Is there a solution to this or should I use ws until this problem is noticed?

Yes, I found the problem. Actually, this is an additional security measure. Bun starts dropping packets if there is a packet sending sequence between a client and a server that exceeds 1 MB. Actually, you can send 1 million packets to different people, but when you try to send to 1 person, Bun sees it as an attack and blocks it. You can increase the limit if you want, but it is not necessary.
If you want to detect this, check this out: https://bun.sh/docs/api/websockets#backpressure
You can change this limit with the backpressureLimit value.
Bun.serve({
  fetch(req, server) {
    if (server.upgrade(req)) return;
  },

  websocket: {
    open(socket) { ... }
    backpressureLimit: 1 * 1024 * 1024 // (1 MB)
  },

  port: 8080
})

